Monitor won't go blank in 22.04
Desktop PC with Ubuntu 22.04, Gnome 42.9, X11. Monitor won't go to sleep even if I set the 'screen blank' to 1 minute. Also, the monitor will wake up shortly after locking and stay at the lock screen, instead of keeps blank.
Have already tried methods like typing command sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3 and choosing gdm3 instead of lightdm, but they don't work.
Does anyone know how to fix it?
